# MS Access SQL - Count of Records that are Currently Open During a Workweek

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a record set that contains

```
 unique ID
 open date
 closed date
```

I want a query to find the count of record that were active during each workweek (52 workweeks in each year).  The data spans several years so the workweeks would not be unique, repeating from 1-52 each year.

Some pseudo-Code would look like:

```
 CountIf( ((OpenDate >= Workweek) & (ClosedDate >= WorkWeek)) 
         OR ((OpenDate >= Workweek) & IsNull(ClosedDate)) )
```

The end result would be a table with the Years, Workweeks, and Count of Active records for that year/workweek.

I have a query that gives me Opened in a workweek:

```
SELECT Year([TABLE].[OpenedDate]) AS [Year], DatePart('ww',TABLE.[OpenedDate])
AS [Work Week], Count(TABLE.[ID]) AS [Count Of IDs Opened]
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Year([TABLE].[OpenedDate]), DatePart('ww',TABLE.[OpenedDate])
ORDER BY Year([TABLE].[OpenedDate]), DatePart('ww',TABLE.[OpenedDate]);
```

And a similar one for Closed but I just can't wrap my head around how to get Active during each Workweek.

**Edited to add:**

Example Data:

```
No  Opened Date Closed Date
1   20-Apr-15   23-Apr-15
2   22-Apr-15   04-May-15
3   27-Apr-15   01-May-15
4   29-Apr-15   04-May-15
5   29-Apr-15   05-Jun-15
6   04-May-15   20-May-15
7   04-May-15   07-May-15
8   05-May-15   20-May-15
9   05-May-15   20-May-15
10  06-May-15   20-May-15
11  06-May-15   20-May-15
12  06-May-15   20-May-15
13  07-May-15   20-May-15
14  11-May-15   26-May-15
15  11-May-15   26-May-15
16  13-May-15   26-May-15
17  18-May-15   26-May-15
18  20-May-15   01-Jun-15
19  21-May-15   03-Jun-15
20  12-Oct-15   07-Jul-16
21  02-Nov-15   26-Jul-17
22  06-Nov-15   30-Nov-15
23  09-Nov-15   26-Jul-17
24  08-Feb-17   05-May-17
25  13-Feb-17   
26  13-Feb-17   14-Aug-17
27  07-Mar-17   17-Mar-17
```

Comment: Some years also have a week 53. What about those?

Comment: You main problem is your "Active during that week" logic. I would check for active by checking that the open date is less than the week's end and the close date is more than the week's start (or null).

Comment: SunKnight0 you are correct. I have changed the `<=` to a `>=` in my pseudo-Code. Good catch, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took some time but I solved my own problem with a combination of solutions posted here.
I made table with 4 columns:

```
tbl_WorkWeeks
 cYear
 cWorkWeek
 FirstDay
 LastDay
```

I populated it with years from 2010-2030, workweeks 1-52 (or 53 as needed), the first day of the given work week and the last day of the given work week.

I then ran this query:

```
SELECT tbl_WorkWeeks.cYear, tbl_WorkWeeks.cWorkweek,
    tbl_WorkWeeks.FirstDay, tbl_WorkWeeks.LastDay,
    Sum(
        IIf(
            (
                ([tbl_MyDataTable].[OpenedDate] <= [tbl_WorkWeeks].[LastDay])
            AND (
                (([tbl_MyDataTable].[ClosedDate] >= [tbl_WorkWeeks].[FirstDay])
                 OR
                 ([tbl_MyDataTable].[ClosedDate] Is Null))
                )
            )
        ,1,0)
    ) AS [Active RecordID]
 FROM tbl_WorkWeeks, tbl_MyDataTable
 WHERE [tbl_MyDataTable].[RecordID] Is Not Null AND [tbl_WorkWeeks].[FirstDay] <= Now()
 GROUP BY tbl_WorkWeeks.cYear, tbl_WorkWeeks.cWorkweek, tbl_WorkWeeks.FirstDay, tbl_WorkWeeks.LastDay
 ORDER BY tbl_WorkWeeks.cYear, tbl_WorkWeeks.cWorkweek;
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need a table with all years and weeks, lets call it `allYears: {Year, Week}`

Also I guess you have a main table for your records, lets call it `stores` to give it some context. Otherwise you do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM `active_stores`
```

Finally your actives record will be `active_stores`

Then your query is:

```
SELECT allYears.Year,
       stores.ID,
       COUNT([active_stores].ID) as total_active_weeks
FROM allYears, stores
LEFT JOIN active_stores
  ON allYears.Year = Year([active_stores].[OpenedDate])
 AND allYears.Week >= DatePart('ww',[active_stores].[OpenedDate])
 AND allYears.Week <= DatePart('ww',[active_stores].[ClosedDate])
 AND stores.ID = [active_stores].ID
GROUP BY allYears.Year,
         stores.ID
```

Comment: I created a structure to reflect your design here (fyi you have a typo, your first and last allYear should be allYears). The Query will not run. It errors out and selects the first allYears with "Syntax error in JOIN operation".

Comment: can you try adding one join condition each time? first `SELECT * FROM allYears, stores`, then `LEFT JOIN active_stores
  ON allYears.Year = Year([active_stores].[OpenedDate])` and so on to see which cause the error

Comment: Now I remember in access you have to put everything in parenthesis when doing `JOINS`

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditional aggregation where you count *active* records by same week of *OpenedDate* and *ClosedDate*. Below exaggerates indentation for readability.

```
SELECT Year(t.[OpenedDate]) AS [Year], 
       DatePart('ww', t.[OpenedDate]) AS [Work Week], 

       SUM(IIF(((
                DatePart('ww', t.[OpenedDate]) = [Work Week] AND
                DatePart('ww', t.[ClosedDate]) = [Work Week])
               ) OR
               (
                DatePart('ww', t.[OpenedDate]) = [Work Week] AND
                t.[ClosedDate] IS NULL
               ),
           1,
           0)) AS [Count Of Active IDs]

FROM myTable t
GROUP BY Year(t.[OpenedDate]), DatePart('ww', t.[OpenedDate])
ORDER BY Year(t.[OpenedDate]), DatePart('ww', t.[OpenedDate]);
```

To test above, here is the unit level (non-aggregate) query:

```
SELECT Year(t.[OpenedDate]) AS [Year], 
       DatePart('ww', t.[OpenedDate]) AS [Work Week], 

       t.[OpenedDate],     
       t.[ClosedDate],

       IIF(((
             DatePart('ww', t.[OpenedDate]) = [Work Week] AND
             DatePart('ww', t.[ClosedDate]) = [Work Week])
            ) OR
            (
             DatePart('ww', t.[OpenedDate]) = [Work Week] AND
             t.[ClosedDate] IS NULL
            ),
           1,
           0) AS [Active ID]

FROM myTable t
```

Comment: I would like to say big thanks for the formatting and the attempt. These are getting me close to what I want. Still not 100%. If I leave them as is there is a missing ")" before AS in the first 2 examples and they return all 0. If I change SUM to COUNT I start to get data but it is just Counting and Grouping the OpenDates not Active.

Comment: Correct. I forgot to close the `SUM()`. So add a closing `)`. Really, we are tagging *True* conditions with 1 and *False* with 0 and summing which is equivalent to counting. The reason they may return all zero is your logic. Can a record open and close in same week which is essentially what you are attempting to count here.

Comment: Yes, a record could be open and closed in the same week.

Comment: And with parenetheses check queries still returned zeros? Very interesting. Oh well, answers like these are coin flip without example data!

Comment: I have added some sample data. Not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I updated to only use the last query as counting from Jan 1 is problematic due to what week year starts. These return non-zeroes per posted example. I do add the unit level version of aggregate to show how the `IIF()` outputs.